# Веб-сервер для Ruby

Tags: веб-программирование, ruby

Хочу написать минимальное web-приложение на Ruby. Какой HTTP-сервер для этого можно использовать?

Сервер должен быть:

1. Простым в установке и использовании. На бессмысленный пердолинг жалко времени.
2. Поддерживать cgi-скрипты
3. Сервер должен быть под линукс
4. Фреймворки не нужны, от сервера мне нужен только запуск скриптов

Comment: Просто интересно, а зачем вам CGI? У него ж огромный оверхед.

Comment: Мне нужно создать скрипт, работающий с БД, который выдает форму с капчей. Я обучаю нейронную сеть на распознавание капчи и пишу флудер с ее использованием. Слишком сложное приложение мне писать не нужно.

Comment: Это не объясняет, зачем CGI. Как раз та самая лишняя сложность, которая вам не нужна. :)

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/company/1cloud/blog/272471/ подробно о веб серверах, про CGI забудьте

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Если обязателен CGI почему бы не взять любой сервер, поддерживающий CGI? Только приложение вряд ли получится минимальным. Вам придется изрядно поработать и пописать. Если вы хотите минимальное приложение лучше исходить хотя бы с уровня Rack-приложения - это такой гем (библиотека по-рубишному), который позволяет взаимодействовать с ruby web-серверами. Он де факто стандарт в отрасли, все современные сервера ориентируются на него. Если писать на чистом **Rack** - у вас будут очень компактные по коду и потреблению памяти Web-приложения на чистом Ruby.

Тогда с одной стороны вы получите действительно минимальное приложение, не перегруженное сверх-тяжелыми гемами вроде ActiveSupport, которые разом прибавляют по десятку мегабайт к процессу. При условии, конечно, что сами избежите соблазна их использования. С другой стороны вы получаете доступ ко всей современной Web-инфраструктуре Ruby и его Web-серверам. Плюс вы найдете поддержку сообщества, потому что рубистов, работающих в Web за пределами Rack очень и очень не много.

### Минимальное Rack-приложение

Установите гем rack

```
gem install rack
```

Далее создайте файл config.ru

```
class Hello
  def call(env)
    [200, {'Content-type' => 'text/plain'}, ['Hello world!']]
  end
end

run Hello.new
```

Запустить сервер можно командой

```
rackup
```

В отчете которой будет сообщено, на каком порту и IP-адресе слушает сервер (все конфигурируется уже на уровне конфигурационного файла Web-сервера).

### Web-cервера

**Unicorn** - классический fork-сервер, создает несколько процессов. Так как работает исключительно с процессами, потребляет довольно много памяти. Чтобы создать дополнительное соединение, вам нужно скопировать (fork-нуть) целый процесс, а процессов нужно много, так как связь блокирующая - одно соединение - один процесс. Если много медленных клиентов - беда, нужно много процессов и много памяти. Клиенты по-долгу держат соединения и для новых клиентов нужно больше новых соединений, т.е. процессов, а в конце-концов и памяти.

**Thin** - сервер на EventMachine, один мастер-процесс в цикле обходит все соединения и проверяет их в неблокирующем режиме. Не боится медленных клиентов, просто не дожидаясь ответа идет опрашивать других, возвращаясь к текущему на следующем цикле. Выгода заключается еще в том, что он не переключает контекст потоков/процессов, экономя ресурсы при высокой частоте обращений со стороны клиентов. Однако, со стороны backend у него такая же классика, как у Unicorn - если ваше приложение задумается (полезет в базу данных или куда-то по сети) весь процесс встанет и сервер подвиснет. В продакшене не видел, но если отдавать какую-нибудь статику, наверное не плохо справится.

**Puma** - комбинированный вариант, EventMachine и несколько веркеров на backend-стороне. Не боится медленных клиентов и медленных ответов с сервера.

Это сервера написанные на Ruby. Статику, как правило, стараются отдать быстрым nginx, динамику передают Ruby-серверу, при необходимости тоже кэшируя страницы.

Comment: На всякий случай проясню: все эти сервера используют расширения на C. На чистом Ruby написан только Webrick (пожалуй, не заслуживающий упоминания %) ). А Unicorn, в отличие от традиционного форк-сервера, форкается в **фиксированное** число воркеров, и когда всем находится занятие, обслуживание поступающих клиентов просто прекращается. ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯ Поэтому его обычно прикрывают `nginx`'ом.

Answer (score 0):

В случае если необходимость в поддержке, например php(например когда на сервере несколько приложений, в том числе использующие php), то возможна связка apache + phusion passenger(необходимо ограничить количество потоков для passenger, т к иначе быстро съест всю память)